# How to center QPixmap while Painting it inside QItemDelegate of QListWidget

Tags: qt, qpainter, qlistwidget, qpixmap, qitemdelegate

I'm painting a QPixmap inside the QItemDelegate of QListWidget. Each QListWidgetItem is of different dimensions. Inside the

```
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
```

function of QItemDelegate, I want to paint QPixmap with center Alignment inside the QListWidgetItem. option.rect() gives the geometry of the item with which I can calculate the center position and paint accordingly, but I want to know the better approach for this alignment.Can some one let me know the answer?

Comment: Given all of those strategically placed Qs, I'm going to assume that this question is about Qt?

Comment: @gokula  can u tell exactly what u want...

Comment: @CodyGray Yup. This is about Qt. You can see the tag also for that

Comment: @shobi I'm painting a QPixmap over a QListWidgetItem. I want to paint it in center aligned way. I want to know whether there is any in built paint method to paint centered aligned inside QListWidgetItem.
If possible can you please answer my question posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618912/filtering-mouse-click-event-in-qlistwidget

Comment: @CodyGray I've one more question in this link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618912/filtering-mouse-click-event-in-qlistwidget). If possible please answer it

Comment: I added the tag... Yes, now you can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the dimensions of your QListWidgetItem? If so, just paint the QPixmap yourself with something like:

```
painter->drawPixmap(
    (item->width() - pixmap->width()) / 2,
    (item->heigt() - pixmap->height()),
    pixmap
);
```

Comment: yes, we can calculate the dimenstions od QListWidgetItem by option.rect. 
The code mentioned by you is what exactly I have mentioned as calculating ourself. I wanted to know is there any better approach for this other than calculating ourself

Comment: @gokulakrishnangopalakrishnan, better approach? IMO, the best way is to do it yourself so you can control exactly how it's going to look. I wouldn't delegate to the framework for this kind of simple rendering (even for complex ones, I still think that the best way is to do it "manually". It brings a lot less headaches going around framework glitches and limitations).

Comment: @Laurant thanks. I've one more question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618912/filtering-mouse-click-event-in-qlistwidget). If possible, can you please answer that?